# Strange result in plotting data using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, debugging

I'm trying to plot this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=5cm,
    width=\linewidth]
    \addplot[smooth,blue] plot coordinates {
    (27,177)
    (28,223)
    (29,240)
    (30,227)
    (31,201)
    (32,186)
    (33,183)
    (34,187)
    (35,192)
    (36,191)
    (37,188)
    (38,174)
    (39,168)
    (40,169)
    (41,195)
    (42,249)
    (210,413)
    (211,473)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and this is the result:
[image: plot result (strange)]
>

As you can see, my data contains increasing non repeating value on x axis. However, there's a curve that bend back at around `x=30` to `40` and `x=210` to `220`. However when I remove the last 2 data `(210,413),(211,473)` the resulting plot seems normal:

[image: plot result (normal)]
>
Any idea for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The problem is the `smooth`, remove that and it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the `smooth` option, it look like this :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please notice that when someone posts an answer as a comment, is it considered quite impolite to post the very same thing as an answer. We do it quite often, [as discussed in the meta.TeX.SX site](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments).